# Stored procedure to delete a row as well as all foreign references within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tree

I have table AB with columns A , B and is_active where A is primary key and B references column A e.g the entries are (1,null,1),(2,1,1),(3,null,1),(4,2,1),(5,3,1),(6,5,1) and so on. So if I delete entry with primary key 1, then rows should get updated to (1,null,0),(2,1,0),(3,null,1),(4,2,0),(5,3,1) i.e. is_active is set to zero on deletion for all the referenced rows.I need to write a stored procedure for it.Its something like a tree deletion but what would be stored procedure for it?

Comment: you should look into `trigger`, it allows for this kind of cascade behaviour

Comment: @kostyan : Can u site an example?

Comment: examples vary by db flavor, google `create trigger %yourdb%` should point you to the right examples

Comment: a simple trigger wont work since its a case of cascading.

Comment: For **what database** is this? SQL is just the query language - used by many database. Please update your tags and let us know if this is for MySQL, Postgres, DB2, Oracle, SQL Server or something else entirely...

Comment: @marc_s It is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server then your procedure might look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recursive_delete(@id INT)
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  WITH tree(a, b, is_active) AS
  (
    SELECT a, b, is_active
      FROM table1
     WHERE a = @id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.a, s.b, s.is_active 
      FROM tree t JOIN table1 s
        ON t.a = s.b
  )
  UPDATE s
     SET s.is_active = 0
    FROM table1 s JOIN tree t
      ON s.a = t.a
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/849f5/1)** demo

Comment: Can u even explain the logic behind your proc?

Comment: The query uses [recursive common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to pull a parent and all its child rows. Then in UPDATE we join the actual table with the resulset from the CTE to update only rows that we need.